# COVESA/vSOMEIP : Communication between two devices without service discovery with static routing not working

Tags: vsomeip

I am trying to establish the communication between two devices (device1 10.10.1.91/32 and device2 10.10.1.92/32) using vSOMEIP making service discovery as False using UDP protocol.

I am using the static routing concept and have changed the configuration (json) file by adding unicast address under Services for both sender and receiver.
I expected the data would be sent.
But the data is not sent.

1. Can someone help with if any other changes needs to be made in the configuration for it to run.
2. What does the sender and the receiver code look like without service discovery with static routing?